# How to map a list of models in to another model from Firebase Firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a Flutter application where I am using two models, specifically the `Assignment` model and `Task` model.

The `Task` model is mapped from the document snapshot to various child models, i.e. `SimpleTask`, `HardTask`, and `ExtremeTask`.

I have a sub-collection named `ASSIGNMENTS` under a user document where I keep the assignments.
Also, under an assignment document there is a sub-collection named `TASKS`.

> Overview
>
> ```
> User document
> \- ASSIGNMENTS sub-collection
>    \- Assignment document
>       \- TASKS sub-collection
> ```

**This is where the question is raised.** In the `Assignment` model I have a List of tasks. A task is a document inside the subcollection, so I can't figure out how I should map this value.
I would like some suggestions about this. I am using GetX for state management fyi.

```
class Assignment {
  final String id;
  final List<Task> tasks;
  final DateTime registeredAt;
  final bool finished;
  final int checkPoint;

  Assignment(
      {@required this.id,
      @required this.tasks,
      @required this.registeredAt,
      @required this.finished,
      @required this.checkPoint});

  factory Assignment.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map data = doc.data();
    return Assignment(
      id: doc.id,
      registeredAt: DateTime.parse( data["registeredAt"].toDate().toString()),
      finished: data['finished'],
      checkPoint: data['checkPoint'],
      tasks: 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to handle this task manually. because firebse databse not support deep linking.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to deliver the assignment id and use that to stream the collection I would like to target.